Tags disappeared after edit
I don't know how  to repro, but I observed one case of tags that disappeared after an edit on this post. Refreshing the page fixed the issue, but that's still unexpected. I was using the latest version of Chrome on Windows 10.
.

Example 2 (link to post).
Example 3 (link to post).


Possibly related: Inline tag editor disappears after live refreshing a question

Yep, different problem ^ but definitely related to the same issue. Can confirm this has happened to me as well for over a year.
